# Returning void from method to prevent execution

Tags: c++, if-statement, return

I am attempting to exit a method which returns `void` after checking a condition (I realize this would be easier if I threw an exception, but I'm trying to avoid that for this project). I have the code below, which should return out of the `if` statement, if I am interpreting it correctly, but the entire method is still executing. Is there a problem in the code somewhere (I can post more if needed), or is there a better way to write this without exception handling?

```
void Rational::divide(Rational b) {
    if (b.numerator == 0) {
        cout << "Cannot divide by zero." << endl;
        return;
    } else if (b.numerator != 0) {
       numerator = numerator * b.denominator;
       denominator = denominator * b.numerator;
       reduce();
    }
}
```

EDIT: I've updated the code to reflect some suggestions; just to clarify, the `if` statement itself is executing correctly (if b is zero, I get the error message) - once the error message is printed, the remainder of the method continues to run.

EDIT 2: Updated with `else if` revision.

Comment: Check why your condtion is false. You should check if denominator is equal to zero, not the result of the calculation.

Comment: Your if statement is actually checking if the numerator is 0. You need to change it to just be if ( b.denominator == 0 )

Comment: @Rubix Rechvin I'm pretty sure the if statement is doing exactly what's intended. The function is dividing by `b` and we need to make sure that the reational value isn't zero, hence checking if the numerator is zero. Chances are that the `b` parameter's numerator is not actually exactly `0`.

Comment: @MarkB Ah, since it is a Rational class, are we inferring that we are going to divide "this" by b? Therefore in order to avoid an error, we need to assert that b.numerator isn't 0? I think I got tripped up by the error message. It should be something like "Divisor cannot be zero"

Comment: So it prints the message and still runs the rest of the code?

Comment: Why don't you try encasing the rest of the code in an else statement? That would at least guarantee that only one block is exclusively run

Comment: @RubixRechvin Yes, that's what's happening. I tried enclosing the remainder of the code in `else` (`else if`, actually), but that doesn't seem to have worked either.

Comment: With the else if, is it still running both blocks of code?

Comment: Yes, both blocks are still running.

Answer (score 0):

And that is what you are doing. You probably want to do something like this in your `if`statement: `if((double)b.denominator == 0.f)`.

You should also be careful when comparing with floats or double due to the way they are represented in memory. It will almost never be exactly zero, so you should compare with an epsilon.

Comment: It is not impossible for a divide to produce zero, it just requires the numerator to be zero.

Comment: You shouldn't use `==` with `double`.

Comment: You could always use: if (b.denominator < 0.0001 && b.denominator > -.0001) instead of ==

Comment: @RubixRechvin True, fixed it and removed.

Comment: Edited to take into account the accuracy of using `==` with double; however, the problem was not with the condition itself, but with exiting the method after the return was executed.